# ADF forEach inside ul unexpected behaviour

Tags: jsp, jsf, oracle-adf

I am trying to generate a dynamic unordered list in an ADF page.

The code used is:

```
<ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
    <af:forEach var="menu" varStatus="vs"
        items="#
        {navigationContext.defaultNavigationModel.listModel['startNode=/, 
        includeStartNode=false']}">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <af:goLink id="pt_gl3" text="#{menu.title}"
                    destination="#{menu.goLinkPrettyUrl}"
                    targetFrame="#{menu.attributes['Target']}" />
            </li>
    </af:forEach>
</ul>
```

**So, the expected result is:**

```
<ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
   <li class="nav-item">...</li>
</ul>
```

**The actual result is:**

```
<ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto"></ul>
<div>
    <li class="nav-item"></li>
    <div>
        <a dir="rtl" data-afr-tlen="4" id="T:pt_gl3" class="xf6" data-afr-fcs="true" href="/webcenter/portal/Test/pages_home" target="">Home</a>
    </div>
    <div></div>
</div>
<div>
    <li class="nav-item"></li>
    <div>
        <a dir="rtl" data-afr-tlen="8" id="T:j_idt131" class="xf6" data-afr-fcs="true" href="/webcenter/portal/Test/pages_newpage" target="">New Page</a>
    </div>
    <div></div>
</div>
```

Anyone have an idea why it's generating divs before the list items ?

Comment: It's not generating divs before the list items, it is generating them around list items. And did you check if it does not happen when you don't use an ul but some other tag?

Comment: You doing something wrong. Faces tags and html shouldn't mixup. Actually you shouldn't have html tags inside jsf page at all

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
<ui:repeat xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets" value="#
    {navigationContext.defaultNavigationModel.listModel['startNode=/, 
    includeStartNode=false']}"... >
```

instead of af:forEach and see if you notice any difference.